# Which type of url should use in android for sending request to server?

Tags: android, url, http-post

I am new in android development. Recently i'm working on a online based android application project. To send a **post request**  in server i'm using this type of url along with **ip address**:

```
public void makeRequest() {
     InsertData task1 = new InsertData();
     Log.d("Arif", "working on pre");
     task1.execute(new String[]{"http://209.151.146.23/class/project/subject_request.php"});
}
```

When i'm using defult url like this then it's also working:

```
  http://www.sitename.com/class/project/subjec_request.php
```

My question is:

**what is the differece between this two type of url?**

**Is there any security issue?**

**And which type of url should i use in my project.**

Thanks in advance. I'm confused about this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
http://209.151.146.23/~shihabmr/class/project/subject_request.php
```

and

```
http://www.sitename.com/class/project/subject_request.php
```

is the hostname. Using `www.sitename.com` instead of `209.151.146.23/~shihabmr` is ideal as it means you aren't hard-coding the hostname which could potentially change in the future. When you use `www.sitename.com` a DNS lookup request will occur and resolve in the IP address `209.151.146.23` which is very useful.

In terms of what balu b said in his answer (now gone), he is right to say you should use POST requests if you don't want to disclose the payload directly, but it can still be intercepted. Neither POST or GET is securer than the other in that way and so if you need security you should use [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the two url are :
1º- The first one go to an STATIC IP(209.151.146.23) and the second one go to a domain
2º- I dont know what is "~shihabmr"

Assuming you dont need "~shihabmr".You should use the second one since it its always better to target a domain than an static IP, if the server IP changes you will need to upload a new version with the new IP but if you use the domain, you only need to change the IP in the domain

Answer (score 1):

You have got idea of difference between those.
Now, to develop android app when you use your PC as server using software like xampp you must use the ip. But, when you will publish your app or connect to web server it is better to use URL.